# After setting a value to a var it still contains its default value

Tags: angularjs, service, default-value

In my Model I default certain variables to `null`

```
angular.module('qbs.models').service('loginModel', function () {

this.name = 'loginModel';

var data = {
    //.......
    loggedIn: null,
    loggedOut: null
    //.......
};

this.set = function (key, value) {
    data[key] = value;
};

this.get = function (key) {
    return data[key];
};

this.getAll = function () {
    return data;
};
});
```

Later on after succesfully loggin in I set `loggedIn` to `true`

```
loginModel.set('loggedIn', true);
```

When I read out the Model with `console.log` the property is set correctly. However, when retrieving the value with

```
`loginModel.get('loggedIn');`
```

I still get `null`

The question is how this can be. Seems like I am refering to a property on another Object?!

Comment: Is the set and get functions called in the same controller?

Comment: Have you tried to add "data" to  the local object (this)?

Comment: yes, same names and tried referencing it to this.data - still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your **loginModel** service calls are sequential? could be async issue...

Anycase, to avoid '**this**' scopes collision try to externalize the service methods (get,get,getAll...) with **return** statement, like this:

```
angular.module('qbs.models').service('loginModel', function () {

var data = {
    //.......
    loggedIn: null,
    loggedOut: null
    //.......
};

function set (key, value) {
    data[key] = value;
};

function get (key) {
    return data[key];
};

function getAll () {
    return data;
};

return {
  name: 'loginModel',
  get: get,
  set: set,
  getAll: getAll
};

});
```

Comment: something fishy is going on here.. even this doesnt work. I output the complete object and the property has the changed value. I retrieve it with the getter and its still null.even when I directly access it through `loginModel.data.loggedIn` its null while the complete object has the updated values

Comment: it was the a-sync issue. I was reading out the vars before the where set. The object however gets a-sync updated in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
var data = {
    //.......
    loggedIn: null,
    loggedOut: null
    //.......
};
```

to

```
this.data = {
    //.......
    loggedIn: null,
    loggedOut: null
    //.......
};
```

it should be change the value of `data`
and then you can use like `loginModel.data.loggedIn`.

Comment: the thing is, I want data property to be private, closure like. So only accesible via getter/setters

Comment: and, actually, changing `var data` to `this.data` doesnt solve the issue. Still same behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, then only your changes will be reflect to 'data'.

Comment: Did you change all the `data` to `this.data`.